# Compactness in $L^p$ and $L^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, arzela-ascoli

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a Borel probability space. Suppose we have a Banach space of functions on $X$ $(B,\|.\|)$ such that the unit ball of $B$ is compact in $L^p(X)$ for all $p>1$. Can we say that the unit ball of $B$ is compact in $L^\infty(X)$? (Note there is no compactness condition on $X$).

Edit: I probably should mention that $B\subset L^\infty$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ satisfies $\|f\|\leq \|f\|_p$ for all $p>1$ and all $f\in B$.

This relates to a problem I am looking at and had me stumped for a while. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For my purposes we may assume $f\in L^\infty$.

Comment: Since $\mu(X)<\infty$, we have for $f\in B$
$$
\|f\|_{\infty} = \lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p.
$$

Comment: Did you get the inequality sign in $\|f\|\leq \|f\|_p$ right? As is, it implies that the topology induced by $L^p$ norm is stronger, hence compactness in $L^p$ topology implies compactness in $B$, hence $B$ is finite dimensional.